# React-Table change center text (page 1 of n)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, properties, react-table

Hello and happy new year :)

I coded a little react App and it works just fine. The only problem is my React-Table. My whole site is in german language and react-tables default is of course english. So I searched a little bit on the internet and found out I can change the "previous" and "next" button by props.

[image of my props](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81fD7.png)

[my pagination on the website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOt1s.png)

But I didn't found a solution how to change the "Page 1 of 3" to "Seite 1 von 3" like we would say in germany. Would be grateful for every help!

PS: I hope it is enough information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using React-Table v6? If so, I found this on the [official docs](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table/tree/v6#props). There are the props for `pageText` and `ofText`, you could try changing those and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in this [issue](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table/issues/196#issuecomment-310997817) and in other answer you should be able to pass text as prop.